# Webservice POST call with Base64 value throws exception "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException"

Tags: java, spring, web-services, post, base64

I have a simple class.

```
public class SolrModel {
    private Base64 param;
    //setter
    public Base64 getParam() {
        return param;
    }
    //getter
    public void setParam(Base64 param) {
        this.param = param;
    }
    public SolrModel(Base64 param) {
        this.param = param;
    }
    public SolrModel() {
    }
}
```

This is a controller class handling a POST request.

```
@RestController
public class SolrController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/getdata", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public SolrDocumentList getStatus(@RequestBody SolrModel sm) {
        SolrAction sa = new SolrActionImpl();
        return sa.getSearchData(sm.getName());
    }
}
```

After I make REST call, service throws exception.

```
WARNING: Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.util.Base64] from String value ('dmlub2Q='); no single-String constructor/factory method
    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4d809754; line: 2, column: 18] (through reference chain: test.solr.models.SolrModel["param"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.util.Base64] from String value ('dmlub2Q='); no single-String constructor/factory method
    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4d809754; line: 2, column: 18] (through reference chain: test.solr.models.SolrModel["param"])
Aug 12, 2015 7:22:40 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver logException
WARNING: Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.util.Base64] from String value ('dmlub2Q='); no single-String constructor/factory method
    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4d809754; line: 2, column: 18] (through reference chain: test.solr.models.SolrModel["param"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.util.Base64] from String value ('dmlub2Q='); no single-String constructor/factory method
    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4d809754; line: 2, column: 18] (through reference chain: test.solr.models.SolrModel["param"])
```

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: What's the structure of Base64 class?

Comment: Its Java 8 default import java.util.Base64;